# Compare the 2 folders and find files which are different and move the different files alone to another folder using unix command

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have 2 folders `AA` and `BB`. `AA` contains 2 files:

```
1.txt
2.txt
```

`BB` contains 3 files:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

I need to move any files which are only in one of these directories to another directory `CC` using a Unix shell script.

In a real scenario I need to be able to handle lots of files.

Comment: Accepted your answer

Comment: you should click on the green check/tick mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should move the files which are only in one of the directories (untested; it will *only* work if you have simple paths; that is, no whitespace or special characters):

```
for path in $(diff -qr AA BB | grep 'Only in' | sed -e 's/^Only in //;s/: /\//')
do
    echo "$path" CC/
done
```

If this prints the right paths, replace `echo` with `mv`.

Comment: Thanks ,..I am getting the filename But there will be lakhs of files ..how to handle it in loop and copy the files alone in seperate folder..please help